# Replacing characters using map

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a password encryptor but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

```
var replacementMap = {'a' : 'm', 'b' : 'h', 'c' : 't', 'd' : 'f', 'e' : 'g', 'f' : 'k', 'g' : 'b', 'h' : 'p', 'i' : 'j', 'j' : 'w', 'k' : 'e', 'l' : 'r', 'm' : 'q', 'n' : 's', 'o' : 'l', 'p' : 'n', 'q' : 'i', 'r' : 'u', 's' : 'o', 't' : 'x', 'u' : 'z', 'v' : 'y', 'w' : 'v', 'x' : 'd', 'y' : 'c', 'z' : 'a', }

var charToBeReplaced = password;

string bleh = charToBeReplaced.replace(charToBeReplaced, replacementMap[charToBeReplaced]);

console.log(bleh);
```

How exactly do i take user input and then use it to replace it based on me conditions?

Comment: `string bleh` Is this [tag:Java]?

Comment: It's intended to be JavaScript but I'm still learning the ins and outs of it. I have a bad habit of hybrid coding in C# as it feels similar to javascript.

Comment: Without know what environment you are coding for it will be impossible to help you -- what does clinetside mean for you?

Comment: @Soren Local scripting in Atom.io.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is not serious but just for learning purposes. Because as said in the comments, this could lead to **BIG** troubles (major security whole).

```js
var replacementMap = {'a' : 'm', 'b' : 'h', 'c' : 't', 'd' : 'f', 'e' : 'g', 'f' : 'k', 'g' : 'b', 'h' : 'p', 'i' : 'j', 'j' : 'w', 'k' : 'e', 'l' : 'r', 'm' : 'q', 'n' : 's', 'o' : 'l', 'p' : 'n', 'q' : 'i', 'r' : 'u', 's' : 'o', 't' : 'x', 'u' : 'z', 'v' : 'y', 'w' : 'v', 'x' : 'd', 'y' : 'c', 'z' : 'a', }

var password = prompt("Enter passwor: ");

// bleh should be initialized
var bleh = "";
// loop through all chars of password one by one
for(var i = 0; i < password.length; i++){
  // get the current character lowercased
  var char = password.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
  // append to bleh its equivalent value (note that if there is no key for this char undefined will be appended instead)
  bleh += replacementMap[char];
}

console.log("'" + password + "' becomes '" + bleh + "'");
```